# Conditional probability calculation for altering a sequence of data

Tags: pr.probability

I am trying to understand a paper with the hope of implementing it in code. I have a data sequence and would like to alter an element based on given probabilities.

Say I have datapoint $X = [0,1,2,1,0,2,0,1,0,0]$, where the elements belong to the set $D = [0,1,2]$, and the 'general' probability that a data point can change is $p = 0.2$. Then the probability that the data point $x_1$ will be zero is $1-p$, as 0 is the correct value: $1-0.2 = 0.8$. The probability that $x_2$ will be 1 is set at $p/(m-1)$ where $m$ is the length of $D$. So $P(x_1,1)$  and  $P(x_1~,2) = p/(m-1) = 0.2/(3-1) = 0.1$ as the probabilities that $x_1$ can change to either $1$ and $2$, respectively. The probability $x_1$ is $0.8$ so $x`_{i,1} = 0$ (the new data sequence).

The next step is to let the new data point be $d_\alpha$. We are to check the conditional probabilities $P(x_j = d_k | x_{j-1} = d_\alpha)$. This is the portion I'm having trouble understanding with. I just checked some references that $P(A|B) = P(A \cap B)/P(B)$. I am trying to assign $P(B) = 0.8$ as this was the probability that $x_1 = 0$ has occurred. I do not know how and where was $P(A \cap B)$ based and calculated, yet the table I am referencing says that the conditional probability that $x_2 = 0$ | $x_1 = 0$ is $0.58$, $P(x_2 = 1$ | $x_1 = 0)$ is $0.4$, and $P(x_2 = 2 | x_1 = 0)$ is $0.02$. After this, their 'general' probabilities are set that $P_{x_2},0$ is $0.2$, $P_{x_2},1$ is $0.8$, $P_{x_2},2$ is $0$ (if the conditional probability is below the $\tau$ threshold = $0.05$, the 'general' probabilities are set to zero). Based on the figure below, I am troubled by how steps two, three, and so on are calculated. I wanted to cite the authors, but it is anonymous for peer review.

[Altering of a dataset. Red text shows that the data point is altered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq38n.png)

[Found the public paper here.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.09555.pdf)

Please let me know if more context is needed, I myself have been trying to understand this for days. Thank you!

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your text. Can you show the paper you try to understand?

Comment: @DieterKadelka, I have added the link. Fig 2 shows the toy data algorithm, and Section 4.1 is what I'm trying to understand.